# Get dash-dot and dash-dot-dot border using CS

Tags: css, border, border-layout, box-shadow

I want to create borders with style **dash-dot** and **dash dot dot**. They should look like in images below.

[image]

[image]

I know that HTML does not support it currently. Are there any other ways to simulate the same. I also want to be able to adjust the border width according to my needs.

Comment: the duplicate will not give you the *exact* result you want but the main technique to use. Simply adjust it to get what you want

Comment: Well in that case you need `border-image` to set your desire border as an border image, Because dashed and dotted are 2 separate border style you cant merge like this